# How to install without overwriting linked dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have some dependencies that consists of packages that I'm developing myself, and have linked them with "npm link" and "npm link @myspace/mypackage". But since they are dependencies I also have them as such in my package.json.

The problem I face is that when I want to install a new package with "npm install some-package", npm tries to find also my linked dependencies online. But I haven't published them yet (or they have not been updated with the latest changes). So I have to remove them from the dependency section of package.json every time I want to install something.

Is this the way its supposed to work or am I using the link procedure in the wrong way?